# Sliding tile puzzle game, with video (youtube) background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I'm currently making together a simple 4x4 tile sliding puzzle game using jQuery using a stock picture. However, I was asked if it was possible to create a version of it utilizing a youtube video or similar.

I think it is possible, but I don't think it's *practical*. Ignoring the point that it'll make the sliding tile game harder with moving pictures - the only way that I have thought it could be done is to create 15 video clips, one for each section, or load up a youtube video 15 time and position it accordingly in each one of the containers.

While I think the latter option would be the 'easiest', once all the clips are loaded you have the issue that you then need them all to play simultaneously and hope that they don't 'buffer' out.

I wondered if anyone either knew of a way to make a series of youtube play simultaneously (not just a play command on a list of them, but play them when they are all at least partially buffered. I tried with a simple 'play all' command on a series of embedded videos and each one took a certain amount of time to buffer) or if someone could think up a more efficient or simple way of it possibly being done in a web browser without the use of Flash. I don't think there is, but maybe someone knows of a way that I don't! :)

Comment: Just as an update, I found http://ajaxian.com/archives/open-web-video-puzzle which suggests someone has done something similar with the HTML5 canvas element, although not with a youtube video. The site is down, but I found his github which has the main source in it: https://github.com/fczuardi/openvideopuzzle/blob/master/templates/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a particularly efficient way to do this, but this site does play several HTML5 video tiles and it is quite fast:
http://www.viiideeeooo.de/

The optimal solution would be if there was a way to make many copies of the single decoded video stream, but that probably isn't possible in a web browser.

Comment: I seem to have found a solution using HTML5 which appears to work fairly well - the only issue being you have to have access to the <video> tag, which means if embedding an iFrame it won't work unfortunately.